# How to move EFI folder to C drive

Tags: windows, ssd, efi, nvme, disk-management

I want to remove an SSD from my main rig to use it in a retro machine. However I've must have placed a EFI folder there by accident when I reinstalled windows 10 on a larger NVME drive.

[image]

120GB drive is the one I want out of my pc, 500GB is my linux drive, E: is my 1TB data drive, the last one is my win 10 drive
Is there a way to move that partition without destroying my installation of Windows?

Comment: What do you mean by "EFI folder"? The EFI System Partition (ESP) is on the 500 GB drive. It doesn't look like there's any boot-essential stuff on the 120 GB drive. D: is not an ESP: firstly because Windows doesn't say it is, secondly because almost no systems can EFI-boot from NTFS.

Comment: there is a folder called EFI on the D drive and I can't remove it

Comment: Is there actually any problem? Does the PC stop booting when you remove the drive?

Comment: This is trivial to test, and it's highly unlikely NOT to cause any problems doing said testing. Pull the drive and see if the system boots. Run boot repair if the system doesn't boot.

Comment: ok the 120 gb disk got disconnected, pc boots to windows just fine, thanks